# Translation of Sulfur Hexafluoride in spanish?

Tags: vocabulario, vocabulario-técnico, español-neutral, ciencia

Sulfur Hexafluoride is a gas mixture. I'm using Sulfur Hexafluoride at work and I need to translate some documents into Spanish. Can anyone help me? How do you say Sulfur Hexafluoride in Spanish?

Would it be "Hexafluoruro de azufre"?

---

Por favor, que alguien que me ayude. ¿Cómo se dice "Sulfur Hexafluoride" en Español?

¿Se dice "Hexafluoruro de azufre"?

Comment: Yes, Hexafluoruro de azúfre. A best way to technical translations: go to subject in Wikipedia and change language.

Comment: @Rodrigo, creo que deberías transformar tu comentario en una respuesta. No necesita ser muy extensa, pero dado que parece ser la respuesta correcta y la idea de usar wikipedia es tuya, debería ser tuyo el crédito de tener una respuesta para esta pregunta. Propongo además poner la fórmula SF6 para que quede claro que se trata del mismo compuesto y quizá un [link a la página](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexafluoruro_de_azufre)

Comment: @Diego: OK. Me parecío que "yes" no alcanzaba para respuesta.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, [Hexafluoruro de azufre](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexafluoruro_de_azufre). Is an inorganic gas known as greenhouse gas and voice modifier (the reverse effect of helium).

A best way to technical translations: go to subject in Wikipedia and change language.

Comment: Azufre no lleva tilde.